# How to write a karma-jasmine test case for $http.get in angularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, service, karma-jasmine

I have a service:

```
(function () {
    angular.module('app').service('MyAppService', MyAppService);
    MyAppService.$inject = ['$http', 'testUrl'];
    function MyAppService($http, testUrl) {
        var service = {
            testFunction: testFunction        
        };
        return service;
        function testFunction() {
            /*testurl is my backend API*/
            return $http.get(testUrl)                
                .error(function(){
                    return;
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    return response.data;
                });
        }
    }
})();
```

I call this in my controller as:

```
        testControllerFunction();
        function testControllerFunction() {
             MyAppService.testFunction().then(function (response) {
                app.testResponse = response;  //This my http response
                console.log(app.testResponse);
            });
        }
```

I am writing a karma test case for successful $http.get request in the MyAppService as:

```
describe('MyAppService', function () {
        var MyAppService,http;
        beforeEach(function() {
            module('app');
            inject(function ($injector) {
                MyAppService = $injector.get('MyAppService');
                testUrl = $injector.get('testUrl');
                http = $injector.get('$httpBackend');
            });
        });

        it('should call the backend testurl ', function () {
            MyAppService.testFunction();
            http.expectGET(testUrl);
        });
    });
```

But this does not seem to be working? Where did I go wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [flush](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#flushing-http-requests) the `$httpBackend`

```
    it('should call the backend testurl ', function () {
        http.expectGET(testUrl);            
        MyAppService.testFunction();
        http.flush();           
    });
```